# Not able to inject an instance of ObjectMapper using guice injector in java application

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jackson, guice, objectmapper

My Module class is like below :

```
public class JacksonModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("dynamicWidgetDeserializer")
    public static ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
        SimpleModule simpleModule = new SimpleModule();
        simpleModule.addDeserializer(Block.class, new BlockDeserializer());

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
                .registerModule(simpleModule);

        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

Trying to inject `ObjectMapper` instance in `BlockDeserializer` class like below :

```
public class BlockDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Block> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
    @Inject
    public BlockDeserializer(@Named("dynamicWidgetDeserializer") ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        super(Block.class);
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public BlockDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    @Override
    public Block deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        .
        .
        .
        
    }
}
```

But here the injected instance of `ObjectMapper` is `null` . Please keep note that i am trying to create a object of `BlockDeserializer` in my `getObjectMapper` method , is this somehow related with why i am getting null ?

Comment: I am not sure about Guice, but if it were Spring (which I guess works similarly), when you create an object manually via constructor (`new BlockDeserializer()`), the Spring does *not* manage the instantiation and no bean is injected. I guess it will be something similar. You should not mix manual instantiation and framework managed instances. Notice that even the constructor which you call does not have any argument, it is *not* the constructor with the injection!